# AngularJs- Form validation directive. The password confirm is always invalid

Tags: angularjs, validation, ionic-framework, angularjs-directive

I have signup form in my ionic app ([the code available here](http://codepen.io/AmirHMousavi/pen/VpOzeR)), the signup view has it own controller. the password confirm has a Directive to check the match with the main password. the register button is disabled till the form is valid. but **the form never becomes valid**. **the `password_c` input is always invalid**.

```
<ion-view view-title="Register Form">
  <ion-content>
    <form ng-submit="signup()" name="regForm" novalidate>
      <div>
        <label for="email" .....></label>
        <label for="password" ......></label>
        <label for="password_c">
                <input type="password" id="password_c" name="password_c" ng-model="registerForm.password_c"  valid-password-c required>
                   <span ng-show="regForm.password_c.$error.required && regForm.password_c.$dirty">Please confirm your password.</span>
                    <span ng-show="!regForm.password_c.$error.required && regForm.password_c.$error.noMatch && regForm.password.$dirty">Passwords do not match.</span>
            </label>
                <button type="submit" ng-disabled="!regForm.$valid">
      </div>
    </form>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

and this is the directive:

```
   .directive('validPasswordC', function () {
      return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function (scope, elm, attrs, ctrl) {
          ctrl.$parsers.unshift(function (viewValue, $scope) {
            var noMatch = viewValue != scope.regForm.password.$viewValue
            ctrl.$setValidity('noMatch', !noMatch)
          })
        }
      }
    })
```

I do `console.log` the `ng-show` condition; when the passwords matchs, the condition becomes undefined.

```
console.log(!regForm.password_c.$error.required && regForm.password_c.$error.noMatch && regForm.password.$dirty)
```

separately; first the `.required` become undefined then `.noMatch`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't test it now, but I believe `$parsers` expects you to return a value unless you have a parser error.
Try to add a `return` in your code:

```
ctrl.$parsers.unshift(function (viewValue) {
    var noMatch = viewValue != scope.regForm.password.$viewValue;
    ctrl.$setValidity('noMatch', !noMatch);
    return viewValue;
});
```

Comment: just to know, why in pure AngularJs apps no return is needed and works? like in this example: http://jsfiddle.net/thomporter/UZrex/1/